# When styles-old.less from Magento/backend theme is used?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, theme, frontend, admin-panel

When Magento 2 backend theme `styles-old.less` is used?

I see only `styles.less` linked in the admin panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is added in `magento/theme-adminhtml-backend/Magento_Backend/layout/default.xml` on line 11.

```
<css src="css/styles-old.css"/>
```

It is then removed in `magento/theme-adminhtml-backend/Magento_Backend/layout/styles.xml` on line 10. I'm not sure how to find out what pages this file applies to.

```
<remove src="css/styles-old.css"/>
```

### Update

The file does load on some pages in the admin, if you go to `system > cache management` you can see it's used there.

[image]

Comment: Pages using this file are those using `<update handle="styles" />` in their layout xml file.